# Need to pass object from child to parent Class in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, parameter-passing, parent-child

I am new in extJs. so I need some help for pass object from Child component/class to Parent. My code is given below.

My parent class is

```
  Ext.define('My.Parent', {
     extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
     initComponent:function()
     {
// suppose I want object here which passes from child.
       this.callParent(arguments);
     }
 });
```

and my child class is

```
 Ext.define('My.Child', {
    extend: 'My.Parent',
    initComponent:function()
    {   
// Suppose I have one object like var Json = {name:'John'}; 
// and I want to pass this object in parent class's init method.
       this.callParent(arguments);
    }
```

});

can anybody help me? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Just store it in the instance using `this`. This is standard OOP.

```
Ext.define('My.Parent', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    initComponent:function()
    {
        alert(this.myObject);

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

Ext.define('My.Child', {
    extend: 'My.Parent',
    initComponent:function()
    {   
        var Json = {name:'John'};
        this.myObject = Json;

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```